# How to add class to input field on error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

is there any chance in Laravel 4 to simply add a class e.g. "error" to a form field after validation error?
I thought the Form Helper will do that...

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you just have to check your errors for a certain error on a field when outputting the form field, and if it has an error, give it the class of `error`.  I'm not sure of your variable names, but hopefully you get the idea...

```
// Some validation
$validator = Validate::make($input, $rules);

// If it fails, pass errors into view.  
// This could be confusing, you should check http://laravel.com/docs/validation#error-messages-and-views for more info
if($validator->fails()) {
    return View::make('someform')->withErrors($validator);
}

// withErrors() will flash the validation messages to an errors variable.  
//This is just some shorthand syntax that's checking for an error on email and if there is something, it will give the class of error else it will give a blank class
{{ Form::text('email', array('class' => $errors->has('email') ? 'error' : '')) }}
```

Comment: at the moment I make the inputs like that: `code`{{Form::text('username', '', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}`code` so how can I extend my class="form-control" or is there any other way to add error class? Thanks

Comment: You can have multiple classes by having a space between them.  So if you need `form-control` class, just add that to both scenarios.  `{{ Form::text('username', array('class' => $errors->has('username') ? 'form-control error' : 'form-control')) }}`